# How to draw this custom layout in react-native

Tags: android, react-native, layout

I am new to React-native and I have to draw this exact image. I know how to draw it in Android but not in react-native.

I have studied the official docs [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html) but unable to get a clear view for this particular view.

Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't give the exact answer, but I can give you some direction.

```
<View //screen view>
 <View //this view is for the inputs>
  <InputText  //input text from react native 
   has some properties, like placeholder, styles and onChange function>
  <InputText> 
  <InputTextWithCounter  //I suggest you create a component that
   returns a view with a inputText and this counter,
   that can be made with react-native buttons or some other library>
  <InputText>
 <View>
 <View  //View used for the confirm button or other parts of the screen>
  <Button  //Buttons are generally made from a text with touchable opacity>
  </Button>
 </View>
</View>
```

Forgot to mention

A header can be made on the view too, but generally, the header is part of the react native lib you are using, if it is react-native-navigation, you can check here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/header-buttons.html